# window form : How to scroll a panel without scrollbar for window touchscreen device

Tags: .net, winforms

I make the calendar in day view by using panel.

I have added Lable1 for time, lable2 = partition between time, lable3 for description in panel.

I set autoscroll property of panel to false

I have attach the image. In window touch screen device, if i remove the scroll bar then i am not able to scroll the panel. please give me suggestion to scroll without scroll bar in touch screen.

[image: This is the panel how look like]

Comment: Please explain yourself more clearly. Add some code and/or show a Screenshot... I've no idea what you are trying to tell us

Comment: Yeah, your question is so vague! At least add a screenshot or put some code so people might be able to help you.

Comment: The usual problem with a panel without a scrollbar is not just that it doesn't scroll, the user has no idea whatsoever that it *could* scroll.  Create usable UI and you'll automatically have less problems.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what type of usable UI should I create?